# Mui-Datatable header invisible if sort is true

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I make use of the MUI-Datatable library. If I set the sort option to true, the header disappears. That means it is there but is invisible. As soon as I change it to false everything is visible again.

[image: sort: true,]

[image: sort: false,]

I'm not sure what is going on, the code is pretty strait forward. May be a bug? Or libraries fighting each other?

```
export default function Customers2()
{
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const columns = [
        {
            label: 'Id',
            name: 'cust_id',
            options: {
                filter: false,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Name',
            name: 'cust_name'
        },
        {
            label: 'Address',
            name: 'cust_address',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Zip',
            name: 'cust_zip',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'City',
            name: 'cust_city',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Country',
            name: 'cust_country',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Email',
            name: 'cust_email',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Phone',
            name: 'cust_phone',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Category',
            name: 'cust_category',
            options: {
                filter: true,
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Active',
            name: 'cust_active',
            options: {
                filter: true,
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) =>
                {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <Switch checked={value} />
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
        },
    ]
    const options = {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        print: false,
        download: true,
        pagination: true,
        search: false,
        selectableRowsHeader: true,
        sortFilterList: true,
        viewColumns: true,
        selectableRows: true
    };

    //data fetching
    const fetchData = async () =>
    {
        await fetch('//localhost:5000/getCustomers', {
            'method': 'GET',
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => { setData(data) })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
    useEffect(() =>
    {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (

       >
            < MUIDataTable
                title={'Customers'}
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}

            />
```

Dependencies in my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "mui-datatables": "^4.2.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.30.0",
    "react-qr-code": "^2.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-table-sticky": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-component": "^2.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Comment: Can you create sandbox for this?

Comment: Could you create a sandbox and share it with us here pls ?